# Can't store the return value of .map in NEXT.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to store the return value of the map into a variable but I'm getting this error of expected ) or const is reserve value. I can do this on react.js but I'm having this issue in next.js

```
<div className='w-3/5 flex flex-wrap justify-between mx-auto pt-24'>
          {props.map((prop) => (
            let rating = `${prop.review_scores.review_scores_accuracy}`;
            
            <div
              key={prop._id}
              class='max-w-sm overflow-hidden shadow-xl flex-shrink'
            >
              <img
                class='w-full'
                src={prop.images.picture_url}
                alt='Mountain'
              />
              <div class='px-6 py-4'>
                <h2 class='text-md font-bold  mb-1'>{prop.name}</h2>
                <p class='text-gray-700 text-base truncate'>
                  {prop.description}
                </p>
                <div>
                  {[
                    ...Array(fullName),
                  ].map((star, index) => {
                    return (
                      <FontAwesomeIcon
                        key={index}
                        icon={faStar}
                        className='w-4 h-4 fill-current text-indigo-900'
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this part of code:

```
{props.map((prop) => (
  let rating = `${prop.review_scores.review_scores_accuracy}`;
            
  <div
    key={prop._id}
    class='max-w-sm overflow-hidden shadow-xl flex-shrink'
  >
```

with:

```
{props.map((prop) => {
  let rating = `${prop.review_scores.review_scores_accuracy}`;

  return (
    <div
      key={prop._id}
      class='max-w-sm overflow-hidden shadow-xl flex-shrink'
    >

  [REST_OF_CODE]
)}
```